# mysqldump ошибка 1064

Tags: mysql

столкнулся с ошибкой 1064 в mysqldump мне нужно сделать дамп но вылетает ошибка.
гугл не помогает тк всё что он выдает было написано давно и они не подходят из-за версии
код: mysqldump example > sample.sql
вывод:ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'mysqldump example > sample.sql' at line 1

Comment: только номер 1064  без описания?

Comment: где именно команду делаешь: просто в оболочке или в клиенте mysql? винда или линукс?

Comment: в клиенте mysql

Comment: а надо в оболочке вроде как

Comment: я чайник так что могу не понять. оболочка это клиент на подобе dbeaver?

Comment: попробуй запустить дамп без `> sample.sql`. все должно вываливаться на экран. на чем остановится

Comment: таже проблема. снова ошибка

Comment: mysqldump — это программа, которую нужно запускать в командной строке операционной системы, а не внутри mysql